# How can I suggest a swipe-to-right gesture in a list on a mobile device?

Tags: android, ios, gesture, user-experience

I have done live user testing for a list in my app, and have come to an interesting puzzle.

A list, specifically a single-column table in iOS, may often have a swipe right gesture for more actions, like the twitter app and mail app, and a million other apps.  But when important functionality is embedded in the UI beyond that action, and a user cannot figure it out, the only thing that comes to mind to alleviate that is something like the accessory button, ie. a right-pointing triangle or chevron button.

There is probably another way but it's not coming to me. Maybe making the rows taller than normal?

Comment: This would be a better question for the [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange.

Comment: Okay, I haven't been to that site. I'll check it out, but if anyone decides to respond, I'll accept a good answer.

Comment: I believe `UIPageControl` has a standard indicator, never have seen it at table row though. Well, AppStore iOs app could be build with sectioned tables and pageControls. If your table design is similar that would be a good user experience.

Comment: Just adding a note: I've joined the UX stack exchange after John Leehey's suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was meant as a comment but was rejected as too-long.

So after thinking more about this, the ideal solution is a visual clue, rather than painfully obvious text saying "swipe a row for more options". Perhaps when a list (UITableView, etc) is shown and rows (UITableViewCell, etc) are created and added, then as they appear an animation begins of the main visible content sliding into place in the OPPOSITE direction of the desired swipe animation, with a minimal visual indicator afterward, reminding the user that the content is moveable!

Sound good? Optionally, immediately before the animation begins, any underlying content may be shown for a split second (if its supposed to appear underneath). Sweet!